# Find First occurrence of a user and assign values to it

Tags: python, pandas

Here's what my data look like:

| user_id | prior_elapse_time | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 115 | **NaN** | 0 |
| 115 | 10 | 1000 |
| 115 | 5 | 2000 |
| 222212 | **NaN** | 0 |
| 222212 | 8 | 500 |
| 222212 | 12 | 3000 |
| 222212 | NaN | 5000 |
| 222212 | 15 | 8000 |

I found similar posts that teach me how to get the first occurrence of a user:

```py
train_df.groupby('user_id')['prior_elapsed_time'].first()
```

This would nicely get me all the first appearance of each user. However, now I'm at a loss at how to correctly assign 0 to the NaN only at **the first occurrence of the user**. Due to logging error, you can see that NaN appears elsewhere, but I only want to assign 0 to the boldfaced NaN.

I also tried

```py
train_df['prior_elapse_time'][(train_df['prior_elapse_time'].isna()) & (train_df['timestamp'] == 0)] = 0
```

But then I get the "copy" vs. "view" assignment problem (which I don't fully understand).

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `df` is sorted by `user_id`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.user_id.diff().ne(0), 'prior_elapse_time'] = 0
>>> df
   user_id  prior_elapse_time  timestamp
0      115                0.0          0
1      115               10.0       1000
2      115                5.0       2000
3   222212                0.0          0
4   222212                8.0        500
5   222212               12.0       3000
6   222212                NaN       5000
7   222212               15.0       8000
```

Alternatively, use `pandas.Series.mask`

```
>>> df['prior_elapse_time'] = df.prior_elapse_time.mask(df.user_id.diff().ne(0), 0)
```

---

If not sorted, then get the indices via groupby:

```
>>> idx = df.reset_index().groupby('user_id')['index'].first()
>>> df.loc[idx, 'prior_elapse_time'] = 0
```

---

If you want to set `0` to only those places where it was previously `NaN`, add `pandas.Series.isnull` mask to the columns.

```
>>> df.loc[
        (df.user_id.diff().ne(0) & df.prior_elapse_time.isnull()),
        'prior_elapse_time'
    ] = 0
```